# Compute inverse for local charts.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces, inverse-function

I've got the revolution surface $S$ generated by a regular, simple curve $\alpha:(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3, \alpha(u)=(f(u),0,g(u))$. I have to prove that the map $$\vec{x}: (a, b) \times (c, d) \to S : (u, v) \mapsto (f(u) \cos( v), f(u) \sin( v), g(u))$$ being $(c,d)$ any real interval of length $2\pi$, is a local chart of $S$ and that any two different local charts of this kind are compatible, i.e., if $\vec{y}$ is another local chart then $\vec{x}\vec{y}^{-1}$ and $\vec{y}\vec{x}^{-1}$ belong to $\mathcal{C}^\infty$.

To prove that $\vec{x}$ is a local chart, I'm trying to show that it is homeomorphism onto its image. I've already shown that it is continuous and biyective, but I guess I need the inverse of $\vec{x}$ to prove what's left. Does anyone have any idea about how to compute it or al least show that it is continuous and $\mathcal{C}^\infty$?

Comment: You can chop up your chart into little pieces point by point and use the inverse function theorem. There might be a better way, but this will certainly do it. You'll get an explicit formula for the derivative of the inverse, and hence, continuity. This would require some smoothness assumptions on the chart - what does the word 'regular' mean in this context?

Comment: @AlfredYerger I thought of using the inverse theorem but I don't see it clear because the Jacobian wouldn't be a square matrix, so I wouldn't be able to take its inverse, would I?
Regular means differentiable (I think I can assume $\mathcal{C}^\infty$) and non-zero derivative.